# mongoose using $in and only update one with most recent timestamp

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, mongoose

Not sure if this is possible but,
I have few `documents` in a collection.  There are duplicates in the `documents` and the only difference is the `timestamp`

for example:

```
{
    name: 'abc',
    verified: false,
    createdAt: 'timestamp1'
},
{
    name: 'abc',
    verified: false,
    createdAt: 'timestamp2'
},
{
    name: 'abc',
    verified: false,
    createdAt: 'timestamp3'
    },
{
    name: 'eee',
    verified: false,
    createdAt: 'timestamp1'
},
{
    name: 'eee',
    verified: false,
    createdAt: 'timestamp2'
}
```

as can see, there are duplicates for `name` field but I only want to update with most recent `timestamp`, `verified` to `true`

But `timestamp` is really random to catch.

I am able to use `update and $in` but this will update all docs instead of just the one with the most recent `timestamp`

sample of a timestamp which is created by mongoose

```
},
"updatedAt": {
    "$date": "2018-06-08T23:39:49.310Z"
},
"createdAt": {
    "$date": "2018-06-08T23:21:15.669Z"
},
```

this is my simple code using `$in`

```
const names = ['abc', 'eee'];

Model.update({
        'name': {
            $in: names
        }
    }, { verified: true }, { multi: true });
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Which type has your timestamp? Is it really a Date or just a String?

Comment: @MatthiasHerrmann I updated my post with a sample of the timestamp.  The timestamp is created by mongoose itself with `{timestamp: true}` in the schema

Comment: So in different words: Find all entries with certain names in the database and set `verified` and `multi` true for the most recently created entry for this name

Comment: @MatthiasHerrmann yes that is right, thanks for the rephasing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the most recent documents by `createdAt` for the specified names:

```
const names = ['abc', 'eee'];

collection.aggregate(
[
   {$match: {'name': {$in: names}}},
   {$group: {_id: '$name', createdAt: {$max: '$createdAt'}}},
]);
```

Save the result of the query in a variable `result` as `Array` or `cursor`.

Then you can update the documents:

```
results.forEach((newestDocumentForName) => collection.update({_id: newestDocumentForName['_id']}, {/*your set operation*/});
```

Comment: shouldn't this `{$group: {_id: '$name', dates: {$max: '$createdAt'}}},` be `{$group: {name: '$name', createdAt: {$max: '$createdAt'}}},` ?

Comment: No, `name: '$name'` would throw an error - because it wouldn't know which value for `name` to pick and what to group by. The error message sounds like this: "The field 'names' must be an accumulator object"

Comment: In this case I'm grouping by the field called `name` - so the `_id` in this stage is set to `$name`. For documentation about grouping read this: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html

Comment: thanks, even though i didn't do it exactly like yours but the `match and group` helped me out.  I just didn't use the `forEach` and instead I took another step by taking out all the `createdAt` into an array then used `$in` to get all the `createdAt` then update them

Comment: Clean way to get the documents... +1